# WiFi adapter not working on XPS 13 9310, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, dell, xps

I recently received an XPS 13 9310 from my new employer and replaced its operating system with Ubuntu 20.04.

I haven't been able to get the WiFi working correctly - sometimes the adapter will show up and work for a bit, and sometimes it won't.

Ethernet seems to work fine.

All the threads I've found by googling have similar issues but not quite the same and their solutions haven't worked for me - they mostly seem to be using older versions of Ubuntu and fix the problem by upgrading to a later version or the latest kernel. I've tried Ubuntu 21.04 and 18.04 and it didn't change anything.

I've also experienced an issue where the screen will randomly freeze, mouse and keyboard stop responding and I'm forced to power off and on again. I don't know if this is related.

Here are the outputs of various commands that may be helpful:

`lshw -c network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:60531dc000-60531dffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2:3
       logical name: enx00e04c68090d
       serial: 00:e0:4c:68:09:0d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.1.183 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi` when the wifi is NOT working

```
[    2.256709] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.259992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.260085] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.260188] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.260201] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.261462] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.261473] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[    2.261475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.261476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.261653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.313551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX203, REV=0x354
[    2.493386] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: dc:41:a9:a9:29:8c
[    2.528071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[   16.126871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Error sending SCAN_ABORT_UMAC: time out after 2000ms.
[   16.126880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Current CMD queue read_ptr 26 write_ptr 27
[   16.128245] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
[   16.128249] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   16.128251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   16.128253] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   16.128255] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   16.128258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   16.128260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   16.128262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[   16.128264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[   16.128266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   16.128268] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   16.128270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   16.128272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   16.128274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   16.128276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   16.128279] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   16.128281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   16.128283] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   16.128285] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   16.128287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[   16.128289] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   16.128291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   16.128293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   16.128295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   16.128297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   16.128299] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   16.128301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   16.128303] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   16.128305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   16.128307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   16.128309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   16.128311] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   16.128313] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   16.128316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   16.128318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   16.128743] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   16.128746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
[   16.128748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   16.128750] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   16.128753] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80465D2E | umac branchlink2
[   16.128755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac interruptlink1
[   16.128757] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac interruptlink2
[   16.128759] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[   16.128761] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac data2
[   16.128763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[   16.128765] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000037 | umac major
[   16.128768] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD9698065 | umac minor
[   16.128770] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00BAC57B | frame pointer
[   16.128772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886270 | stack pointer
[   16.128774] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0019010D | last host cmd
[   16.128776] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   16.128946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   16.128972] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   16.129026] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   16.129081] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   16.129135] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   16.129189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   16.129244] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   16.129298] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   16.129353] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   16.129407] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   16.129464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   16.129520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   16.129577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   16.131389] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired.
[   16.131637]  iwlmvm dcdbas snd_pcm i915 serio_raw efi_pstore snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 dell_privacy_wmi dell_wmi_sysman ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor snd_rawmidi wmi_bmof snd_seq libarc4 snd_seq_device hid_sensor_als snd_timer hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer drm_kms_helper kfifo_buf snd hid_multitouch hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio cec iwlwifi soundcore rc_core i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect mei_me ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_device mei intel_rapl_common typec_ucsi cros_ec_ishtp cfg80211 cros_ec sysimgblt power_ctrl_logic intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul psmouse i2c_i801 rtsx_pci i2c_smbus nvme intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss i2c_hid idma64 thunderbolt intel_ish_ipc
[   23.295143] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5d68, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   23.295264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x80480ec8
[   23.295281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x163b6
[   23.295287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[   23.296360] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
[   23.296363] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   23.296366] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   23.296368] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   23.296370] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   23.296372] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   23.296374] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   23.296376] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[   23.296378] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[   23.296380] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   23.296382] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   23.296384] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   23.296386] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   23.296388] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   23.296390] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   23.296393] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   23.296395] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   23.296397] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   23.296399] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   23.296401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[   23.296403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   23.296405] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   23.296407] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   23.296409] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   23.296411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   23.296413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   23.296415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   23.296417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   23.296419] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   23.296421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   23.296423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   23.296425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   23.296427] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   23.296429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   23.296432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   23.296866] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   23.296869] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000010, count: 7
[   23.296871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   23.296874] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   23.296876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80465D2E | umac branchlink2
[   23.296878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac interruptlink1
[   23.296880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac interruptlink2
[   23.296882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[   23.296885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac data2
[   23.296887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[   23.296889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000037 | umac major
[   23.296891] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD9698065 | umac minor
[   23.296893] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000FAA4C | frame pointer
[   23.296895] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886270 | stack pointer
[   23.296897] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   23.296899] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   23.297071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   23.297096] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   23.297150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   23.297205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   23.297260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   23.297314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   23.297369] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   23.297423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   23.297478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   23.297510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   23.297568] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   23.297603] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   23.297660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   23.297695] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe!
[   23.297700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   23.297703] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   28.303539]  iwlmvm dcdbas snd_pcm i915 serio_raw efi_pstore snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 dell_privacy_wmi dell_wmi_sysman ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor snd_rawmidi wmi_bmof snd_seq libarc4 snd_seq_device hid_sensor_als snd_timer hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer drm_kms_helper kfifo_buf snd hid_multitouch hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio cec iwlwifi soundcore rc_core i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect mei_me ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_device mei intel_rapl_common typec_ucsi cros_ec_ishtp cfg80211 cros_ec sysimgblt power_ctrl_logic intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul psmouse i2c_i801 rtsx_pci i2c_smbus nvme intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss i2c_hid idma64 thunderbolt intel_ish_ipc
[   28.303740]  iwlmvm dcdbas snd_pcm i915 serio_raw efi_pstore snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 dell_privacy_wmi dell_wmi_sysman ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor snd_rawmidi wmi_bmof snd_seq libarc4 snd_seq_device hid_sensor_als snd_timer hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer drm_kms_helper kfifo_buf snd hid_multitouch hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio cec iwlwifi soundcore rc_core i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect mei_me ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_device mei intel_rapl_common typec_ucsi cros_ec_ishtp cfg80211 cros_ec sysimgblt power_ctrl_logic intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul psmouse i2c_i801 rtsx_pci i2c_smbus nvme intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss i2c_hid idma64 thunderbolt intel_ish_ipc
[   28.303930]  iwlmvm dcdbas snd_pcm i915 serio_raw efi_pstore snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 dell_privacy_wmi dell_wmi_sysman ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor snd_rawmidi wmi_bmof snd_seq libarc4 snd_seq_device hid_sensor_als snd_timer hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer drm_kms_helper kfifo_buf snd hid_multitouch hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio cec iwlwifi soundcore rc_core i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect mei_me ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_device mei intel_rapl_common typec_ucsi cros_ec_ishtp cfg80211 cros_ec sysimgblt power_ctrl_logic intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul psmouse i2c_i801 rtsx_pci i2c_smbus nvme intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss i2c_hid idma64 thunderbolt intel_ish_ipc
[   28.605186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[   28.605213] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[   28.605232] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[   28.605252] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[   28.605922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   28.605941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[   28.605946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   28.605948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[   28.606528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   28.606592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX203, REV=0x354
[   29.631158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5db8, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   29.631398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x80480ec8
[   29.631415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x163b6
[   29.631421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[   29.631625] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
[   29.631629] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   29.631632] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   29.631634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   29.631636] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   29.631638] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   29.631641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   29.631643] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[   29.631645] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[   29.631647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   29.631650] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   29.631652] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   29.631654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   29.631656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   29.631659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   29.631661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   29.631663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   29.631666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   29.631668] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   29.631670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[   29.631672] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   29.631675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   29.631677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   29.631679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   29.631681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   29.631683] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   29.631686] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   29.631688] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   29.631690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   29.631692] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   29.631695] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   29.631697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   29.631699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   29.631701] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   29.631704] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   29.632168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   29.632171] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[   29.632173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   29.632176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   29.632178] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80465D2E | umac branchlink2
[   29.632180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac interruptlink1
[   29.632182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac interruptlink2
[   29.632184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[   29.632186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80480EC8 | umac data2
[   29.632189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[   29.632191] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000037 | umac major
[   29.632193] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD9698065 | umac minor
[   29.632195] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000F6017 | frame pointer
[   29.632197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886270 | stack pointer
[   29.632199] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   29.632202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   29.632372] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   29.632398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   29.632451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   29.632506] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   29.632539] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   29.632593] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   29.632648] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   29.632703] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   29.632758] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   29.632813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   29.632870] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   29.632905] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   29.632940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   29.632996] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   34.764528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi` when the wifi IS working

```
[    2.450034] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.452349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.452428] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.452505] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.452514] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.453823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.453836] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[    2.453840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.453841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.454073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.527880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX203, REV=0x354
[    2.711487] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: dc:41:a9:a9:29:8c
[    2.727934] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: It's interesting that `iwlwifi` reports the wireless device as an AX203 when *most* 9310 models ship with an AX500-series. Does `sudo lspci` also show the wireless device as an AX203? If so, you may need to use a 21.10 daily to use the wireless device, as support was added in kernel 5.11.4 ...

Comment: @matigo it actually doesn't list a device when I do `sudo lspci`: ```00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device a0f0 (rev 20)
```

Comment: According to `lshw`, wifi has no driver. you need to determine your card type and find a driver. Sometimes this is easy, other times not so much..

Comment: try `sudo apt install iwlwifi-firmware` to see if that helps. This is a troubleshooting process, so it may or may not. I am guessing that you will need to dig up a driver off the internet, but it is best to try the simple stuff first. XD Btw I am getting this from the -2 error code. It is a sometimes-fix.

Comment: Suggestions: Update UEFI -and- disable Fast Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with older kernels. I was able to fix this by installing a newer kernel with `apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04-edge` or `apt install linux-image-5.13.0-1009-oem`

You can see a full list of available kernels with `apt list linux-image*`

Ensure that `linux-firmware` is up to date also, or experiment with the latest `wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode -O /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode`

Other things you can experiment with:

- Update the firmware on the device with `fwupdmgr refresh --force && fwupdmgr upgrade`
- Change `wifi.powersave` to `2` in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
- Experiment with kernel cmdline options such as `pcie_aspm=off`, full list available here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.11/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html
- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

Comment: Thanks - I've yet to try everything listed here and test it (testing is difficult because it only doesn't work *sometimes*) but I'm marking this as the best answer for all your helpful suggestions.